# Why is this code giving me invalid content type from Request.Form? (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

This is using ASP.NET Core 2.0 OnGet method of RazorPages.

cs file:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CoreRazor2.Pages
{
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    [BindProperty]
    public int result { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(string operationType)
    {
      string result;
      switch (operationType)
      {
        case "+":
          result = Request.Form["First"];
          break;
        case "-":
          result = "1";
          break;
        case "/":
          result = "2";
          break;
        case "*":
          result = "3";
          break;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

cshtml file:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Calculator";
}

<form method="GET">
<label>First Value: </label>
<input name="First"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Second Value: </label>
<input name="second"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="operationType" value="+"/>
<input type="submit" name="operationType" value="-"/>
<input type="submit" name="operationType" value="*"/>
<input type="submit" name="operationType" value="/"/>
</form>
@Model.result
```

When putting a value in the first form input and clicking on the "+" submit button, the program throws the following exception at Request.Form["First"]:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Incorrect Content-Type: '
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
   at CoreRazor2.Pages.IndexModel.OnGet(String operationType) in c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CoreRazor2\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs:line 17
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory.VoidHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.<InvokeHandlerMethodAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
```

Does anybody have any idea why or could point me toward some helpful documentation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GET based forms pass values via the URL not the form. You need to use `Request.Query["First"]`. Request.Form only works when you're POSTing the form. But since you're using Razor Pages, you can save yourself all of the trouble and just use model binding:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CoreRazor2.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public int Result { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(string operationType, int first, int second)
        {
            switch (operationType)
            {
                case "+":
                    Result = first + second;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    Result = first - second;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    Result = first / second;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    Result = first * second;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we need to receive POST data?

Comment: Then you add an OnPost method.

Answer (score 34):

For generic purposes (as logging) when you need to process all type of HttpRequests use [HttpRequest.HasFormContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.hasformcontenttype?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_HasFormContentType)

Sample code:

```
if (request.HasFormContentType && request.Form != null && request.Form.Count() > 0)
{
            dynamic form = new { };
            foreach (var f in request.Form)
                form[f.Key] = f.Value;
            d.form = form;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be

```
Request.Query["First"]
```

rather than

```
Request.QueryString["First"]
```

Otherwise I get

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'QueryString'